# Understanding promise then handler syntax and semantics

Tags: javascript, promise, arrow-functions

I want to create a function which starts a progress bar effect, creates and executes an "ajax" call, extract the html from the result and stops the progress bar effect - then returns the promise to further processing:

```
function myStart()
{
   ProgressBar_ON(); // initiates some effect on html that ajax call is on the way
   var promise = fetch(url, {headers:'Accept': 'text/html'});
   return promise
          .then(resp => resp.text())
          .then(resp => { ProgressBar_OFF(); return resp; });
}
```

I would like to call it as the following:

```
myStart()
 .then( resp => $("#placeholder).html(resp) )
 .then( ... )
```

The problem is inside the myStart function. The very last "then" I tried to write in 3 ways:

```
// #1 one command only - BAD
.then( resp => ProgressBar_OFF() )
// #2 arrow expression - BAD
.then( resp => { ProgressBar_OFF(); return resp; } )
// #3 old way - but this one works well
.then( function(resp) { ProgressBar_OFF(); return resp; } )
```

Can anybody explain why the #1 and #2 is wrong against #3? Or at least can suggest me some reading about the topic?

It is said that the .then must return a promise (which is an object itself with 2 possible states), and if I inspect the resp in the very first one (.then(resp => resp.text()) I can see it is a quite complex object (created by fetch itself). To extract the resp.text() I can imagine that this is the "return value" of this then, which is given to the very next one, so resp => $("#container").html(resp) can work. Then why the #2 wont?

I saw in some example, that the following is usual in then - which (for me) means that execucte the console.log, then returns ??? the resp itself? If then so why #1 wont work? Note: ProgressBar_OFF() function contains no "return", so returns ?? void?!

```
.then( resp => console.log( resp ) )
```

As I read about the arrow expression: the "resp => ProgressBar_OFF()" means that it returns the value returned by the ProgressBar_OFF() itself. Implied return. I can accept, that in this case it is bad, since the OFF() function returns nothing. The how the console.log call works? In this case ".then( resp => $("#placeholder).html(resp) )" wont be good as well :(

I sink in javascript somewhere I am afraid :( Can somebody lend a helping hand?

Comment: I don't see how the 2nd arrow function could be different in this context. Maybe you had a typo?

Comment: As `fetch()` is a Promise itself, is it necesary to declare and return a variable "promise" ? Couldn't we just do `fetch(url, {headers:'Accept': 'text/html'}).then(resp => resp.text()).then(resp => { ProgressBar_OFF(); return resp; })` ? I am just wondering.

Comment: Yes, but its not the point. I was separated it because I was testing creating Promise from $.ajax() instead of fetch. The remaining .then parts are (almost) the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

```
const returnValue = aPromise.then( callbackFunction );
```

When `aPromise` resolves then the `callbackFunction` will be called and the first argument passed to it will be the resolved value of `aPromise`.

The return value of `then()` will be assigned to `returnValue`. This value will be a promise that resolves to the return value of `callbackFunction`.

---

> ```
> var promise = fetch(url, {headers:'Accept': 'text/html'});
> return promise
>       .then(resp => resp.text())
>       .then(resp => { ProgressBar_OFF(); return resp; });
> ```

In this line of code `promise` is a promise that resolves to a Response object.

Line 2 assigns that Response to `resp` and then calls `text()` on it. The return value of that is a promise which resolves to the content of the response body.

In line 3 that text content is assigned to `resp`. You then call `ProgressBar_OFF()`. You then return the text.

So the second `then` returns a promise that resolves to the same text. This is then returned from the `myStart` function by the `return` statement.

---

> ```
> // #1 one command only - BAD
> .then( resp => ProgressBar_OFF() )
> ```

Here the arrow function returns the return value of `ProgressBar_OFF()`. The value `resp` is lost as it isn't returned to the next `then` in the chain.

> ```
> // #2 arrow expression - BAD
> .then( resp => { ProgressBar_OFF(); return resp; } )
> // #3 old way - but this one works well
> .then( function(resp) { ProgressBar_OFF(); return resp; } )
> ```

These two are equivalent. They should both work. Both call `ProgressBar_OFF` and then return the passed in value.

Comment: As `fetch()` is a Promise itself, is it necesary to declare and return a variable "promise" ? Couldn't we just do `fetch(url, {headers:'Accept': 'text/html'}).then(resp => resp.text()).then(resp => { ProgressBar_OFF(); return resp; })` ? I am just wondering - thank you.

Comment: @JürgenFink — You can always use the result of a function directly without storing it in a variable. That the value is a promise is immaterial.

Comment: And what about resp => console.log(resp) case? it should be the same as ProgressBar_OFF() - however I cannot say what is the return value of the console.log currently. I suppose void. Then using it would destroy the then call chain?